# updating from babel 5 to babel 6 gives error "Super expression must either be null or a function, not object"

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, jestjs

I am upgrading my existing React application from Babel 5 to Babel 6. Application was working fine with Babel5 but after upgrading it to Babel6 I get this error in browser console.

`Super expression must either be null or a function, not object`

Using `babel` config in package.json

```
{
  ...
  "babel": {
     "presets": ["stage-0", "es2015", "react"],
     "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
  }
  ...
}
```

With

`Webpack: 1.12.4`

`React: 0.13.3`

Other Dev Dependencies:

```
{
 "babel-core": "^6.5.2",
 "babel-jest": "^6.0.1",
 "babel-loader": "^6.2.2",
 "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
 "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
 "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
 "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "1.3.4",
 "babel-register": "6.5.1",
 "jest-cli": "^0.8.2",
 "jest-webpack-alias": "2.2.0"
}
```

no errors from webpack

**Edit:**

Error occurs when I extend custom react component. For eg:

```
class A extends React.Component {}

Class B extends A {}
```

Then I see error for `class B`

Please help!

Comment: Can you add an example showing the code causing this error?

Comment: Ok, I searched a bit more and found, that issue exists when I extend custom react component. For eg: class A extends React.Component; and class B extends A; then I see error for class B. Is there any babel plugin to support this ?

Comment: I'm not aware of one. Often you are better off using HoC pattern and avoid inheritance. Quite powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so finally I resolved it. I was using Multiple inheritance in my application and I didn't find any babel plugin that supports it. I searched if React JS supports multiple inheritance or not and I came to know that it

> prefers Compose over Inheritance as it is purely based on functional programming paradigm

so I converted all multiple inheritance instances to use composed component.

Example

```
export function composeA(Component) {
   class A {
     ....
   }

   return A;
}


class B {...}
export default composeA(B);
```